# how to update the date in database table

Tags: php

I want to update my databse to change all the different formats of dates into one format. I want to update different time formats into the format `2016-12-22`.

I get this error:

> 250 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ($res1) at
>   position 0 ($): Unexpected character' in
>
> /hermes/walnaweb13a/b775/moo.manhassurinder/singhaniafarm/test.php:22
>
> Stack trace: #0
>   /hermes/walnaweb13a/b775/moo.manhassurinder/singhaniafarm/test.php(22):
>
> DateTime->__construct('$res1') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /hermes/walnaweb13a/b775/moo.manhassurinder/singhaniafarm/test.php on
>   line 22

```
    $squery = "SELECT date,id FROM `addCutting` ";
       $sresult = mysqli_query($con,$squery);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sresult))
       {
         "<br/>". $res1= $row['date'];
          echo"<br/>". $res= $row['id'];
         /*  if($res1!= date('y/m/d'))
          {
          $result2=  date_format( new DateTime($res1), 'y/m/d' );
          echo $result2;
          }
       }
        */

/* $date1 = new DateTime($res1);
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d'); echo "<br/>"; */
    $date = new DateTime('$res1');
     echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your query in cleaner way, One simple way of storing date in Mysql is to store TimeStamp and manipulate it in required format on record retrive.

Comment: `var_dump($res1)` and let me know the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sresult))
{
    $date= $row['date'];
    $formated_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));

    echo $formated_date;
}
```

Try this hope it works

Referal Link on strtotime [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: do print_r($date) what is the output

Comment: thanks you sir i got it cn you to tel how to update the date in mysql table

Comment: note please that if $row['date'] is NULL or empty you'll be updating with the current timestamp, which might not be desired. Also if $row['date'] is not a valid time string or one not understood by strtotime the code will fail

Comment: UPDATE `addCutting` SET date='
2016-05-11 ' WHERE id='250' Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /hermes/walnaweb13a/b775/moo.manhassurinder/singhaniafarm/test.php on line 5

Answer (score 1):

I think what you what is this instead of the last 2 lines

```
$formated = "";
if(!emtpy($res1)){
    $date = new DateTime($res1);
    if(!emtpy($date)){
        $formated = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}

echo $formated;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I really do not understand what you meant in this comment